# How to calculate a circle's latitude/longitude bounding rectangle?

Tags: geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have a database with latitudes and latitudes.

I want to retrieve all points that are within 1 mile of a given lat/lng point on planet Earth.

I'll do this in two steps: first retrieving the points that are within the circle's bounding rectangle, to take advantage of database indexing, then calculating the exact distances to every candidate point to filter down to the proper results.

*Great Arc Distance* is a well-known algorithm for calculating distance from two given lat/lng points.

But how can I calculate a 2nd lat/lng given a lat/lng and a distance?

**What have I tried**

Google leads me to Great Arc Distance. See above paragraph.

Comment: You mean giving the distance 1 mile, the function must returns lat,long of two points where the distance between them is 1  ?

Comment: I want some mechanism here , where lets say i Have 1 laitude and longitude of current location..... now from this current location i want to find out the other Latitude and Longitude from Database for "1 mile distance". If Database having "Latitude and longitude" between this 1 mile distance, than Java code will return this Lat and long from Database. And after that i want to show this Lat and Long as pin point/annotation in the MAP. But what is the query to return the values of "lat and long" in the MYSQL Table and i should execute it in Java code.

Comment: I edited the question to make it less homework-looking, because I have this same question and it is definitely not homework, and this question is now high-ranked in Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should uses the **haversine** formula to calculate the great-circle distance between two points, you got a starting point and the distance which is 1 mile.

Haversine formula:

```
a = sin²(Δlat/2) + cos(lat1).cos(lat2).sin²(Δlong/2)
c = 2.atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1−a))
d = R.c
```

where :

```
 - R is earth's radius (`mean radius = 6,371km`);
 - Δlat = lat2 - lat1
 - Δlong = long2 - long1
 - atan2(y,x) = arc tan(y/x)
 - d = 1 mile
```

or you can use the **Equirectangular approximation** which is much easier :

```
x = Δlong.cos(lat)
y = Δlat
d = R.sqrt(x² + y²)
```

So what you have is the distance d=1 and the starting point let say (lat1 , long1) so you have to solve the equation and get all the pairs (lat,long) that verify your equation.

Enjoy.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps you should hire a developer? Since your "question" is more like a work request you'd see on sites such as oDesk than it is like a question that helps you solve a problem you are facing after actually doing some work yourself...

Besides, what does "1mile" mean by itself? (answer = nothing)

You really need to supply, along with a DISTANCE of 1 (in miles), a REFERENCE POINT! And the fact you don't know/realise that supports the suggestion:you should hire someone to do this.

Lol.

Comment: Hi I think some kind of misunderstanding is created here..... I am not working for any site such as "oDesk". I want some mechanism here , where lets say i Have 1 laitude and longitude of current location..... now from this current location i want to find out the other Latitude and Longitude from Database for "1 mile distance". If Database having "Latitude and longitude" between this 1 mile distance, than Java code will return this Lat and long from Database. And after that i want to show this Lat and Long as pin point/annotation in the MAP.